# Visual Studio Database Pro Partial Projects Constraints Issue

Tags: visual-studio-dbpro

In Visual Studio 2008 Database edition one can use "partial projects" to allow a database to be separated into multiple projects for deployment and maintainability. I have been looking into doing this with our project but hit the following snag:

If you have project that defines some base tables, and then you have a different project that defines a new set of tables that have constraints pointing to the tables in the first project, DBPro seems unable to map this relationship. The specific error is:

> "CONSTRAINT has an unresolved reference to Table foo" (where foo is in the original DB).

A more concrete example if you'd like to duplicate for yourself the scenario:

- Create a Project called BaseDB.
- Define in BaseDB a table called Users with the following DDL:

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] ( 
      UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
      UserName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  )
  ```
- Export BaseDB as a partial project adding the _BaseDB.files file to your project.
- Create a Project in the same solution called DerivedDB
- Use the Import Partial Project to point to BaseDB, confirming if you like that there's a stub reference in your import files pointing to the Users table in BaseDB.
- Define a table in DerivedDB called PowerUsers with the following DDL:

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PowerUsers] ( 
      PowerUserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
      UserID INT NOT NULL
  )
  ```
- If you do a "Build" at this point, everything works.
- Add a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT in the DerivedDB project from PowerUsers to Users with the following DDL:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PowerUsers]
      ADD CONSTRAINT [PowerUsers_Users_FK]
      FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
      REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] (UserID)
  ```

Performing the above steps should allow you to see the error I'm talking about.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to fix constraint references across database projects?
2. If not, should partial projects then be reserved for series of stored procedures and the base project reserved for *all* DDL of base tables and constraints?